# [A-Z]{2,4} not limiting to between 2 & 4 characters

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, posix, pcre

```
PCRE: /\A[A-Z0-9_\.%\+\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9\-]+\.)+(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)\z/i 
POSIX: /^[A-Z0-9_\.%\+\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9\-]+\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,4}|museum|travel)$/i
```

This regex is correct in every way for my needs except that it allows emails such as jim@f.com. It says these are a match. If I'm not mistaken, doesn't the {2,4} after [A-Z] mean that it has to be between 2 and 4 characters? Could it be a problem with the altercation and museum and travel? I have verified that these are allowed through in my application, and a few  [regex testers.](http://rubular.com/regexes/12473) **Also, I'm fuzzy on whether I did do the PCRE and POSIX correctly. I fear they might both just be PCRE and I'm being ridiculous. AFAIK, JavaScript is POSIX and Ruby is PCRE. So if I didn't get that right, lemme down easy**, it has been a long, long night of learning regexes, in and out, and I'm trying to look badass. :)

Comment: You mean why did I bold that section? If so, I was hoping that someone else that came by might answer that other question. It's not really worded as a question but I was leery of changing any of the actual wording for fear of having it rolled back. So I just bolded that vague section there, ha. Maybe you can help though, because my google-fu is not working or something right now. Am I right in the assumption the ruby's RegEx library is PCRE and JavaScript's is POSIX? Also that's why I unmarked his answer in hopes that he would come back because I couldn't message him. I'll be sure to remark it

Comment: No sorry - I meant that someone marked your question down (to -1), but I thought it was a totally reasonable question, so I gave you a +1, and left the comment :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does, but it's only applied to the top-level domain name (the "com" in your example).

Comment: Just as an aside am I right about PCRE = Ruby and POSIX = Javascript?

Comment: No. Ruby doesn't have Perl Regexps, it has Ruby Regexps. More precisely: Ruby 1.8 has Ruby 1.8 Regexps, and Ruby 1.9 has Ruby 1.9 Regexps, and the two are quite different. (Ruby 1.9 is much more powerful.) Ruby 1.8's Regexps are a totally independent implementation, Ruby 1.9's is based on a heavily modified fork of the Oniguruma Regexp engine. Neither Ruby 1.8 nor Oniguruma are based on anything, except of course that their respective authors know the Friedl book (Mastering Regular Expressions), PCRE, Perl, POSIX BRE and ERE and so on.

Comment: Ah. Thanks very much Jörg, I knew that PCRE was Perl RegExps but I thought it was a standard like POSIX. I had no idea about that book though, have you read it? I'm just really getting started diving into truly understanding what RegExps do. Holiday project. :) Wondering if I need to pick that book up for myself?

Comment: Friedl's book is excellent. If you want to get into the nuts and bolts of regexes, it's the book for you. For a more practical approach, check out http://www.regular-expressions.info or the "Regular Expressions Cookbook" by Jan Goyvaerts/Steve Levithan.

Comment: Javascript regular expressions are based on Perl, not POSIX. I don't know if it's exactly the same as PCRE, but it's similar at least.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby regular expression documentation:

- Ruby 1.8: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#regexp
- Ruby 1.9: http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt

Answer (score 0):

POSIX does not support non-capturing groups `(?:group)` so neither of your regexes are POSIX.  JavaScript does not use POSIX.  JavaScript regular expressions are Perl-style but it doesn't have all the features.  Check the [regex flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) on my site for details.